# Is it okay to send blog update pinging without "weblogUpdates.ping"?

Tags: curl, xml-rpc, ping

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36455/17948

the cURL to send is

```
$ curl <target-pingservice-url> -d 'name=<your site name>' -d url=<your-url> -d rss=/rss.xml
```

As far as I know, every ping include `weblogUpdates.ping`.
I just wonder if above cURL works just fine

If `weblogUpdates.ping` is important, how to include it in the command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [commandline / cron curl Facebook RSS feed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683659/commandline-cron-curl-facebook-rss-feed)